# HQL: Multiple JOIN Collection Query Returns Nothing

Tags: java, grails, hql

I'm trying to write an HQL query that returns the following:

> Their propertyTags are in my inclusionTags
>   OR my propertyTags are in their inclusionTags,
>   AND their propertyTags are NOT in my exclusionTags,
>   AND my propertyTags are NOT in their exclusionTags.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
def thePropertyTags = this.propertyTags
if(thePropertyTags == null || thePropertyTags.size() == 0) {
    thePropertyTags = [ Tag.UNUSED_TAG ]
}

def theInclusions = this.inclusionTags
if(theInclusions == null || theInclusions.size() == 0) {
    theInclusions = [ Tag.UNUSED_TAG ]
}

def theExclusions = this.exclusionTags
if(theExclusions == null || theExclusions.size() == 0) {
    theExclusions = [ Tag.UNUSED_TAG ]
}

List<MyDomain> objects = MyDomain.executeQuery("""
    SELECT DISTINCT o
    FROM MyDomain o

    JOIN o.propertyTags as propertyTags
    JOIN o.exclusionTags as exclusions
    JOIN o.inclusionTags as inclusions

    WHERE o.id != :id
    AND o.isActive = true

    AND (
        exclusions IS NULL
        OR exclusions IS EMPTY
        OR exclusions NOT in (:propertyTags)
    )

    AND propertyTags NOT in (:exclusions)

    AND (
        inclusions in (:propertyTags)
        OR propertyTags in (:inclusions)
    )

""", [id: id, inclusions: theInclusions, exclusions: theExclusions, propertyTags: thePropertyTags])
```

The problem is regardless of inclusion/propertyTags matching, joining the exclusionTags causes nothing to be returned. Removing all exclusion clauses still returns nothing, the only way to get anything to return is to remove the JOIN altogether.

**Domain:**

```
MyDomain {
    boolean isActive = true

    static hasMany = [propertyTags: Tag, inclusionTags: Tag, exclusionTags: Tag]

    static constraints = {
        propertyTags(nullable: false)
        inclusionTags(nullable: false)
        exclusionTags(nullable: false)
    }
}

Tag {
    private static final List<Integer> TAG_TYPES = [...]

    String name
    int type
    String description

    static constraints = {
        name(unique: true, nullable: false, blank: false)
        type(inList: [TAG_TYPES])

        description(nullable: true, blank: true)
    }
}
```

**Update:**

I've changed the inclusions/exclusions to a `LEFT JOIN` like so, but there are still no records being returned if the exclusions are in the query:

```
List<MyDomain> objects = MyDomain.executeQuery("""
    SELECT DISTINCT o
    FROM MyDomain o

    JOIN o.propertyTags as propertyTags
    LEFT JOIN o.exclusionTags as exclusions
    LEFT JOIN o.inclusionTags as inclusions

    WHERE o.id != :id
    AND o.isActive = true

    AND exclusions NOT in (:propertyTags)
    AND propertyTags NOT in (:exclusions)

    AND (
        inclusions in (:propertyTags)
        OR propertyTags in (:inclusions)
    )

""", [id: id, inclusions: theInclusions, exclusions: theExclusions, propertyTags: thePropertyTags])
```

Comment: How does the domain class look like?

Comment: @dmahapatro added the domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem I see is that you are doing an inner join on exclusion tags. This will ensure it will only return records that have exclusion tags. Also you could satisfy the "Their propertyTags are in my inclusionTags" with a "MyDomain" that has no inclusion tags so you should left join that as well

Try this

```
LEFT JOIN o.exclusionTags as exclusions
LEFT JOIN o.inclusionTags as inclusions
```

Then you should be able to simply do this:

```
AND (
    exclusions NOT in (:propertyTags)
)
```

**EDIT**:
OK I have it - The problem is the not in. Hibernate is weird about this. Before I posted the original answer I didn't realize that all the tags are nullable false so it makes no sense to do left joins.

```
MyDomain.executeQuery("select distinct m from MyDomain m join m.propertyTags as pt join m.inclusionTags as it where m.id != :id and m.isActive = true and (pt in (:inclusionTags) or it in (:propertyTags)) and m not in (select m from MyDomain m join m.propertyTags as pt where pt in (:exclusionTags)) and m not in (select m from MyDomain m join m.exclusionTags as et where et in (:propertyTags))", [id: id, inclusionTags: theInclusions, propertyTags: thePropertyTags, exclusionTags: theExclusions])
```

Comment: I updated the question with a LEFT JOIN example, but it still returns nothing if the exclusions are joined in the query

Comment: Thanks for your help, I actually ended up figuring out the same solution earlier today. Anyways, bounty is yours, thanks!